# Get value from text field at a webserver ESP8266

Tags: arduino, webserver, textfield, esp8266

I've made a webserver with an esp8266.

```
 sResponse  = 
"<p>"
"<center>"
"<h1>ESP8266 Web Server</h1>"
"<p>Time <input type='text' name='date_hh' size=2 autofocus> hh <input type='text' name='date_mm' size=2 autofocus> mm <input type='text' name='date_ss' size=2 autofocus> ss</p>"
"<p><a href=\"?pin=FUNCTION1ON\"><button>Save</button></a>"
"</center>"; 
client.print(sResponse);
```

I get the following from the webserver:
[image]
.
If I click on the save button, I want to read the value of the three text fields.

What do I have to do? Or, is there another (better) way to built up a webserver like this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to put the input into a form, then submit the form. GET is simplest; you can reach them from C++ as, ex: `int date_mm = server.arg("date_mm").toInt();`

Answer (score 9):

You can start with this.

You can pass the values as query string arguments with a GET request when the "Save" button is clicked.

You can then access the arguments using `server.arg()`.

```
// Libraries
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>


// WiFi network
const char* ssid     = "your_ssid";
const char* password = "your_password";

ESP8266WebServer server ( 80 );



char htmlResponse[3000];

void handleRoot() {

  snprintf ( htmlResponse, 3000,
"<!DOCTYPE html>\
<html lang=\"en\">\
  <head>\
    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\
    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\
  </head>\
  <body>\
          <h1>Time</h1>\
          <input type='text' name='date_hh' id='date_hh' size=2 autofocus> hh \
          <input type='text' name='date_mm' id='date_mm' size=2 autofocus> mm \
          <input type='text' name='date_ss' id='date_ss' size=2 autofocus> ss \
          <div>\
          <br><button id=\"save_button\">Save</button>\
          </div>\
    <script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js\"></script>\    
    <script>\
      var hh;\
      var mm;\
      var ss;\
      $('#save_button').click(function(e){\
        e.preventDefault();\
        hh = $('#date_hh').val();\
        mm = $('#date_mm').val();\
        ss = $('#date_ss').val();\        
        $.get('/save?hh=' + hh + '&mm=' + mm + '&ss=' + ss, function(data){\
          console.log(data);\
        });\
      });\      
    </script>\
  </body>\
</html>"); 

   server.send ( 200, "text/html", htmlResponse );  

}


void handleSave() {
  if (server.arg("hh")!= ""){
    Serial.println("Hours: " + server.arg("hh"));
  }

  if (server.arg("mm")!= ""){
    Serial.println("Minutes: " + server.arg("mm"));
  }

  if (server.arg("ss")!= ""){
    Serial.println("Seconds: " + server.arg("ss"));
  }

}


void setup() {

  // Start serial
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  // Connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  server.on ( "/", handleRoot );
  server.on ("/save", handleSave);

  server.begin();
  Serial.println ( "HTTP server started" );


}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

Comment: this is way to overkill, even by a long shot. why not just connect to a time server and print out the datetime

Comment: @clockw0rk Offline operation maybe? The server could be in AP mode for all we know. Or for the ability to easily enter an arbitrary non-server time for testing? I agree that the time server is best 99% of the time.

Comment: why `<script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js\"></script>` is needed? no simpler way not relying on G?